# Page.Response.Write()

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, download

i have question regarding `Page.Response.Write()`.

in my code save as popup is getting opened.

```
Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", OpenType + ";filename=" + FileName)
```

but i want it save on my hard disk or drive.

so i put the code below but it doesn't work:

```
Dim w As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(FileName)
w.Write(Page.Response)
w.Flush()
```

what i do to save it on my drive/disk

Comment: What does the code do or does not? Does it throw an exception? Does it leave the original file intact. More information please :)

Comment: it just giving me save as popup but i want to save this generating file in my soltuin /disk/drive

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to save immediately without the "Save As" dialog?

Browsers do not allow this for security reasons.  If it were possible, it would be very easy to distribute viruses, spyware and other malware.

You asked:

> what i do to save it on my drive/disk

The answer is to click the "Save" button on the "Save As" dialog - this dialog cannot be bypassed.

Answer (score 3):

Your server code is running on the server. The web page code is running on the user's browser on the user's computer. They are different computers, and one can't reach out to the other.